# AUTOSAR 8-5-1 - order of initialization

Tags: c++, autosar

Rule ([8-5-1](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf)):

> In an initialization list, the order of initialization shall be following: 
>  (1) virtual base classes in depth and left to right order of the inheritance graph, 
>  (2) direct base classes in left to right order of inheritance list, 
>  (3) non-static data members in the order they were declared in the class definition.

###### MyClass.h

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyStruct m_s;
  MyTypedef m_t;

  explicit Participant(MyStruct &s, MyTypedef t);

private:
  AnotherClass m_r;
}
```

###### MyClass.cpp

```
MyClass::MyClass(MyStruct &s, MyTypedef t)
    : m_s(s), m_t(t), m_r(this) {} // violates A8-5-1 (m_r is marked as violation)
```

The order actually matches the order from the header file. I don't understand why this rule is violated. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What is reporting the violation exactly, and what is the actual error message?

Comment: This could be because the object pointed at by `this` is not fully initialized at that point. If `m_r` tried to dereference the passed pointer as part of its construction, errors could potentially occur. In particular, that could happen if `MyClass` was derived,or had a non-trivial constructor body. The checker could be assuming that this might be the case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The error message is exactly what it says above. Unfortunately, that is all that is displayed to me. A detailed explanation can be found in the AUTOSAR document (page 173), which I linked to in my question above.

Comment: @Frank Do you have any idea how to solve it here?

Comment: @KplnMoon The unsatisfying answer to that would be: Restrict yourself to purely DAG relation graphs at the design level.

Comment: @KplnMoon More realistically, you could have the portion of `MyClass` that `MyStruct` needs be in a base class. I have no idea if that would satisfy the checker, but it would be safe as long as no vtable is involved.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your answers! Both DAP and vtable are new terms for me. So for now I refer to your 2nd answer: I don't understand what exactly you mean by **"the portion of MyClass that MyStruct needs"**. MyStruct is in another file called types.h. It is not in any class.

Comment: @KplnMoon DAG is just a formal way to say: "No circular references"

Comment: @KplnMoon As far as my suggestion goes, it would look like this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YYGvbGbTb. Also, I mispoke, I meant **"the portion of MyClass that MyOtherClass needs"** By vtable I mean: you can't have virtual functions for this to be safe.

Comment: @Frank I solved it by changing all non-static members that were initialized in the class body so that they are **only declared in the class body and are initialized instead in the contructor**. Example: Instead of ```bool m_x = false;``` in the class Body I wrote ```m_x(false)``` in the constructor and declared m_x in the class Body (```bool m_x;```). **Thus AUTOSAR does not complain about the order of initialization anymore.**